# Issues upgrading to schema-registry 2.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

we are currently trying to upgrade from schema-registry 1.0.1 to 2.0.1. We see this is working prior to the upgrade with the following versions: kafka_2.10 version 0.9.0.2.4.0.0, kafka-avro-serializer version 2.0.1, avro version 1.7.7

After the upgrade the same requests successful earlier now fail with HTTP 404 errors:

```
[2016-07-26 10:11:05,748] INFO  - - [26/Jul/2016:10:11:05 +0000] "POST //subjects/thing-avro-key/versions HTTP/1.1" 404 49  4 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:77)


2016-07-26 11:23:00.908 b.s.d.executor [ERROR] 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: "string"
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: HTTP 404 Not Found; error code: 404
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:157) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
```

We checked with CURL and are able to post a schema using an example:

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"  --data '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"string\"}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/Kafka-value/versions
```

We then thought Avro schema: "string" might be the problem, so created a ThingKey schema but still getting a similar error:

```
2016-07-26 11:47:31.347 b.s.d.executor [ERROR]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"ThingKey","namespace":"com.x.platform.messages","doc":"A thing identifier for partitioning","fields":[{"name":"thing_id","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"doc":"Thing identifier"}]}
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: HTTP 404 Not Found; error code: 404
```

We are using the following code to publish the message:

```
ProducerRecord<String, SpecificRecordBase> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, getMessageKey(msg), extractAvroMessage(msg));
producer.send(producerRecord);

public SpecificRecordBase extractAvroMessage(KafkaMessage msg) 
public String getMessageKey(KafkaMessage msg)
```

Any ideas or suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ross

---

**Update**: Fixed - the issue was due to an additional slash in the request path which is causing failures due to stricter validation in version 2.0.1. Full details at: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/388